# Loading a Tcl package written in C (DLL) from .NET assembly

Tags: c#, .net, tcl

I'm writing in C# and want to use tcl.

After searching I found [Tcl/Csharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tclcsharp/) project which does the job, however is missing a package that allows it to work with the registry. I have the package in a form of dll file but I"m unable to load it.

```
class Program 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Interp interp = new Interp();

        interp.eval("puts hello world");     // Works
        interp.eval("load tclreg12.dll");    // Throws TclException Invalid command name "load"
        interp.eval("package req registry"); // Throws TclException "cant find package registry"

        TclObject result = interp.getResult();
        Console.WriteLine(result);

        interp.dispose();
    }
}
```

How can I use this package?

Comment: Unless it is being masked as something else, the `load` command [doesn't appear to be defined yet](http://tclcsharp.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tclcsharp/tcl/commands/) and I'm not sure any of the 3 people that actually downloaded this library have taken the time to implement it either. If you _need_ to do this, then you'll have to get your hands dirty.

Comment: Maybe also of interest would be Eagle (http://eagle.to/), which is a more comprehensive Tcl on the CLR/.NET runtime.

Comment: @schlenk could you please direct me to examples showing how to work with eagle?

Comment: After trying several solution I ended up starting a new TCL interpreter process in the background and redirecting it's input/output. I found a nice "all in one file" [interpreter](http://equi4.com/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

As M.Babcock correctly pointed out, that Tcl/Csharp package you're using is just an attempt to implement a Tcl interpreter on top of the .NET stack, but the [`load`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/load.htm) command is highly special as it (in the "real" Tcl) is intended to load Tcl packages written in C, *and* such packages are supposed to use the [C API exposed by the Tcl runtime](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/contents.htm) itself.  This C API is quite comprehensive and, naturally, making a pure .NET code properly emulate all that C API stuff would be a huge undertaking, if at all possible.

Since Windows registry manipulations are trivially done in .NET, I suppose you have a large legacy program written in Tcl at hand, which you need to call from your .NET program (as you probably estimated that porting that program would be more hassle than making it run as is).  If this is true, I would have taken one of these routes:

- Turn your program into a [starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk) and bundle the resulting executable file along with your "host" program, then just execute it as a separate program.  (That file would be single and have no special dependencies.)
- Write a special wrapper assembly which would use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468) to load the real Tcl runtime (Tcl's shell, `tclshXY.exe` is just a thin program, and the real thing is `tclXY.dll` plus a set of library files, and this is the DLL you're supposed to load).  Then your code could pass the Tcl runtime a script (in the form of the string) which would load and execute the actual Tcl program you need to run.

Comment: If you're using P/Invoke to load the Tcl library, make sure to call `Tcl_FindExecutable` in it first; the argument to it should be a NULL (since there's no shell executable in a normal sense). After that, `Tcl_CreateInterp` gives an interpreter reference that can be used throughout virtually the rest of the API (though note that a Tcl interpreter is tightly bound to its creator thread; _don't use in another thread_).

Comment: I found some TCL wrappers that used the p/invoke approach, and also wrote one my self, but I capt on getting exceptions of memory being written/read.